# Get data from soap envelope zeep

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

I am trying to work with wsdl with the help of python library [zeep](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep). It works fine, but i can't find out how can I get data from request.

My code:

```
# encoding=utf-8
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  # or HTTPDigestAuth, or OAuth1, etc.
from zeep import Client
from zeep import helpers
from zeep.transports import Transport
import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(name)s: %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'zeep.transports': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    }
})
wsdl = 'wsdl_url'
user = 'login'
password = 'password'
my_transport = Transport(http_auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password))
client = Client(
    wsdl, transport=my_transport
)
result = client.service.FunctionName(...)
print result
```

As a result, i get this:

```
{
 'schema': <Schema(location=None)>,
 '_value_1': <Element {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram- v1}diffgram at 0x104ec0098>
}
```

Obviously, it is not what I want. Thanks to logging, I can see, that actually I get the needed information with envelope:

[image: Each row has all inforamtion that I need]

My question is, how can I access the data inside the envelope (I need rowOrders, which are partly displayed on screen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced the same problem. So this is how I did it. This is not the best way to do it, but it can be a start and I wish the maker forgives me.
Also, I am just starting to learn python.

clone the zeep project here:
https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep
and go to that folder.

in transports.py, add this line in the constructor (_ *init* _):

```
self.response = ''
```

and then in the method post, before returning the response, add this line:

```
self.response = response
```

after this, build the package by executing

```
python setup.py install
```

this should be in your virtualenv (if you are using one)

so in your code, you can print

```
print my_transport.response.content
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 8):

Using Zeep version 2.4.0 I was able to get the raw response by passing raw_response option to the client. This tells the client to return Requests response object.

Here's example code:

```
from zeep import Client

wsdl = 'wsdl_url'

client = Client(wsdl)

with client.options(raw_response=True):
    soap_result = client.service.function_name(...)

# Print out text from Requests response object returned    
print soap_result.text
```

Comment: using **Zeep v.3.1.0** just change `client.options` to `client.settings`

Comment: With **Zeep v.4.1.0** it's `client.settings.raw_response = True`